# Getting ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined: running this SQL:

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Name AS "Avatar Name", 
       COUNT(WEAPON_ID) AS "Active Weapons Held |", 
       SUM(W.COST) AS "Total Weapons Cost"
FROM   Avatar A, Weapon_Held H, Weapon W
WHERE  A.Avatar_ID=H.AVATAR_ID AND H.WEAPON_ID=W.WEAPON_ID 
Group by Name;
```

Comment: You need to specify what table `Weapon_Id` is coming from (you should also do it for `Name` as well.)

Comment: And please, do yourself a favor, do not use comma separated tables in your `where` clause instead of `join` (more on this at https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins&)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you have multiple tables in your query that have the same name and it doesn't know where to pull it from.  Try changing your query to the following:

```
SELECT  A.Name AS "Avatar Name", 
        COUNT(H.WEAPON_ID) AS "Active Weapons Held |", 
        SUM(W.COST) AS "Total Weapons Cost"
FROM    Avatar      A
JOIN    Weapon_Held H   ON  A.Avatar_ID=H.AVATAR_ID
JOIN    Weapon      W   ON  H.WEAPON_ID=W.WEAPON_ID 
Group by A.Name;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, use table aliases, but use them *everywhere*:

```
SELECT Name AS "Avatar Name", 
       COUNT(H.WEAPON_ID) AS "Active Weapons Held", 
       SUM(W.COST) AS "Total Weapons Cost"
FROM Avatar A JOIN
     Weapon_Held H 
     ON A.Avatar_ID = H.AVATAR_ID JOIN
     Weapon W
     ON H.WEAPON_ID = W.WEAPON_ID 
Group by Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two or more colums in  these tables named 'Name'?
Please use implicit names like: 'A.Name' or 'H.Name' like:

```
Select A.Name....
Group by A.Name
```